# Determine G-Suite Edition

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I would like to have different pricing and licensing options for a Drive enabled app I am developing, based on the G-Suite edition that the user's account is provisioned with.

What API do I use to determine the Edition used for the currently logged in user?

Also, what is the recommended practice (or options) for who maintains my app's billing with business/enterprise?  Can I determine if the user is a system admin and then show only them the billing/invoice sections of my app?

Comment: probably something in here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/ However i would question wither or not the average user would even have access to this data.  And if its only an admin that has access are they going to want to share that information with you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Admin SDK doesn't feel right.  I'm not looking to admin the account in any way, just want a dependable way to know basic account info.

Comment: Your still looking for info about the gsuite account and the only place that i know of that data existing is in Admin sdk.  I dont have access to a gsuite account anymore so cant test it but try this see what it says https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get  I am betting theres nothing in there about the gsuite account.

Comment: That returns an About Resource which doesn't include edition info. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about#resource

Answer (score 0):

Only resellers can get the Subscription information of their resold customer via API, using https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions/get.

For security the Admin SDK(and any other G Suite API but the reseller API) have access to billing information, the subscription type is considered part of the billing section that is way is not accessible